# How to use regular expressions to say that you need to take the value of Categories = .... & Search = ..... &

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this line.

```
let x = "Categories=All&Search=hat&ListPage=15&Page=1";
```

How to use regular expressions to say what you need to take from the beginning of a line and up to 2 characters &.Categories=All&Search=hat&

Comment: Look into [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Comment: Why not split the string on the `&` and just take the first 2 elements in the resultant array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `/([^&]*&){2}/g` regex to match what you want.

```js
let x = "Categories=All&Search=hat&ListPage=15&Page=1";
let y = x.match(/([^&]*&){2}/g);
console.log(y);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `split` and pass the limit argument, then just reconstruct it back into a string (if you really need the `&` - if not, discard everything *after* the `split`):

```js
let x = "Categories=All&Search=hat&ListPage=15&Page=1";
const res = x.split("&", 2).map(e => e + "&").join("");
console.log(res);
```